# Eclipse in Kubuntu automatically closes

Tags: eclipse

I try to use Eclipse in Kubuntu 14.04LTS but everytime I try to click on a link it automatically closes.

Does anyone use Kubuntu and had the same problem?

Comment: in version 18.04 , Eclipse is running normally

Answer (score 0):

try to changing the GTK theme on System settings -- Application Appearance -- GTK

Some problems on Eclipse are related to this. Do not use Oxigen-gtk.